# accessing same database from multiple process sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to connect to the same database from the different processes using SQLAlchemy is it going to be ok if I create different sessions for different processes. if so please it will be very helpful if anyone gives me a hint or example.
thanks a lot!

Comment: It is not clear what you mean when you say 'different process'. What does that mean, or what exactly are you attempting to achieve?

Comment: I want to interact with the same database from multiple python processes using the python multiprocessing module. what I'm asking is if I create different sqlalchemy sessions for different python processes using sqlalchemy  sessionmaker, is there any problem doing this? because sqlalchemy suggest only one session per application but I need more than one session for my app because my app requires two or more session on different processes. one session for flask app and others for background tasks using multiple processes.